# Why preferredColorScheme has no effect on the view presented by the ColorPicker in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, color-scheme, color-picker

I have an app where I let the user choose the `colorScheme`, so that it can be left in adaptive mode or it can be forced to day or night mode, even if the system scheme of the device is different.

The issue is that the popover presented by the `ColorPicker` does not reflect the chosen `ColorScheme`, but only the system one (of the device).

The proposed code produces a list, which reflects automatically the `preferredColorScheme`, as an example. Then it produces a `ColorPicker` to set the background color and some tappable text to change the `colorScheme` to `setColorScheme`.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ColorPickerTest: View {
    
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @State var setColorScheme: ColorScheme? = nil
    
    @State var selectedColor = Color.green
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            selectedColor.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(1..<6) { n in
                        Text("item \(n)")
                    }
                }
                .frame(height: 500)
                .cornerRadius(30)
                
                ColorPicker("Color", selection: $selectedColor)
                    .fixedSize().padding()
                    .background(colorScheme == .dark ? .blue : selectedColor)
                    .cornerRadius(30).padding()
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Theme:")
                    Text("Adaptive").onTapGesture { setColorScheme = nil }
                    Text("Night").onTapGesture { setColorScheme = .dark }
                    Text("Day").onTapGesture { setColorScheme = .light }
                }
            }
        }
        .preferredColorScheme(setColorScheme)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ColorPickerTest()
}
```

This works well, except for the popover presented by `ColorPicker`, in that case the `setColorScheme` has no effect and only reflects the system scheme, ignoring the imposed `preferredColorScheme`.

Does anyone have a solution or an explanation?

Comment: How about setting the color scheme using `.environment(\.colorScheme, …)` instead?

Comment: It seems like a SwiftUI bug. Their ColorPicker selection view takes colorScheme directly from the system (iPhone Settings: dark/light). It does not consider the provided value from the environment, unfortunately.

Comment: @Sweeper it produces the same result of preferredColorScheme, but does not support optional values and does not work too with the ColorPicker

Answer (score 0):

#### macOS solution:

I don't know how to have SwiftUI's `ColorPicker` automatically apply background color, but I can propose this little hack:

`ColorPicker`'s window is a `NSColorPanel` that we can search in the app's window hierarchy. There we can set its properties.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedColor: Color = .gray
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("Pick", selection: $selectedColor)
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        guard let panel = colorPanel else { return }
                        /// Now we can access all NSWindow/NSPanel/NSColorPanel properties
                        print("\(panel.backgroundColor)") // "Optional(Catalog color: System windowBackgroundColor)"
                        panel.backgroundColor = NSColor(selectedColor)
                        // panel.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
                        // panel.titleVisibility = NSWindow.TitleVisibility.hidden
                        // panel.title = "Random text"
                        print("\(panel.backgroundColor)")
                    }
                }
                .onChange(of: selectedColor) { newColor in
                    colorPanel?.backgroundColor = NSColor(selectedColor)
                }
        }
        .padding()
        .fixedSize()
        .background(selectedColor)
    }
}
```

Note that in `onAppear` we need to "wait" with `DispatchQueue.main.async` for the panel to exist in the app's `windows`array.

You will still have to see how to apply your adaptive color scheme, but that how to apply the color if needed.

You can see from the print output, that the panel's initial `backgroundColor` is "Catalog color: System windowBackgroundColor". So if you want to revert to have it repect the system's scheme, you'd have to set back to this value.

Comment: colorPanel is available only in macOS no? this question is for SwiftUI

Comment: SwiftUI does not exclude macOS. Yes, my solution is macOS-specific.